# Azure B2C custom policy Azure AD Signup failed without proper error description

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to create only signup with Azure B2C custom polices. A user can signup by via either Existing Microsoft Account (or) Email Signup (Local Account).

[image]

Email Signup is working fine. But Creating user Existing Microsoft Account asks me first for admin consent. Once Admin approved to access this app, I am immediately redirecting to my application with this following error message.

> http://localhost:3000/#error=server_error&error_description=AADB2C90037:
> An error occurred while processing the request. Please contact
> administrator of the site you are trying to access. Correlation ID:
> e91b7d69-84c0-4b42-b6ba-a8b7b3416d07 Timestamp: 2023-12-11 13:32:15Z

I am expecting when User Clicks Existing Microsoft Account, It should check the tenant and if user is already created, it should throw an error message. If user is not created it should show the a page user should enter their name and few information. Then user can signup the user to our b2c tenant.

In TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml,

```
<UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
  <OrchestrationSteps>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="InitialiseJourney" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="InitialiseJourney"/>
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection"
      ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="AzureADCommonExchange" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" />

      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AzureADCommonExchange"
          TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AADCommon-OpenIdConnect" />
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange"
          TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when in the token. -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId"
          TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="SendClaims"
      CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />

  </OrchestrationSteps>
  <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
</UserJourney>
```

AADCommon-OpenIdConnect TechnicalProfile defined as,

```
<TechnicalProfiles>
  <TechnicalProfile Id="AADCommon-OpenIdConnect">
    <DisplayName>Existing Microsoft Account</DisplayName>
    <Description>Existing Microsoft Account</Description>
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
    <Metadata>
      <Item Key="METADATA">
        https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
      <!-- Update the Client ID below to the Application ID -->
      <Item Key="client_id">{my-app-client-id}</Item>
      <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
      <Item Key="scope">openid profile</Item>
      <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
      <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
      <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
      <Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">true</Item>
      <!-- The key below allows you to specify each of the Azure AD tenants that can be used
      to sign in. Update the GUIDs below for each tenant. -->
      <!-- Item
      Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000,https://login.microsoftonline.com/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111</Item> -->
      <!-- The commented key below specifies that users from any tenant can sign-in. Uncomment
      if you would like anyone with an Azure AD account to be able to sign in. -->
      <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <CryptographicKeys>
      <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_AADAppSecret" />
    </CryptographicKeys>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="preferred_username" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource"
        DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
      <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
      <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
      <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
    </OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
  </TechnicalProfile>
</TechnicalProfiles>
```

ClaimTransformations are,

```
<ClaimsTransformations>
  <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateRandomUPNUserName" TransformationMethod="CreateRandomString">
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="randomGeneratorType" DataType="string" Value="GUID" />
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="upnUserName" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
    </OutputClaims>
  </ClaimsTransformation>
  <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateUserPrincipalName" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="upnUserName" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string"
        Value="cpim_{0}@{RelyingPartyTenantId}" />
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName"
        TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
    </OutputClaims>
  </ClaimsTransformation>
  <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"
    TransformationMethod="CreateAlternativeSecurityId">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" TransformationClaimType="key" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider"
        TransformationClaimType="identityProvider" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="alternativeSecurityId"
        TransformationClaimType="alternativeSecurityId" />
    </OutputClaims>
  </ClaimsTransformation>
  <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"
    TransformationMethod="CreateStringClaim">
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="value" DataType="string"
        Value="Not supported currently. Use oid claim." />
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="sub" TransformationClaimType="createdClaim" />
    </OutputClaims>
  </ClaimsTransformation>
</ClaimsTransformations>
```

Comment: You need to use AppInsights to debug - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy